# What security concerns must I worry about when writing an auto-update client?

Tags: security, auto-update

I am writing an auto update client.  It's a very simple app that:
  1) Checks a central server to see if an update exists for some application
  2) Downloads the install program from the server if a newer version exists
  3) Runs the setup program

Other than server-side concerns (like someone hacking our site and placing a 'newer' malicious application there), what client-side security concerns must I take into account when implementing this?

My current ideas are:
1) **Checksum**.  Include the checksum in the .xml file and check that against the downloaded file.  (Pre or post encryption?)
2) **Encrypt the file**.  Encrypt the file with some private key, and let this program decrypt it using the public key.

Are both or either of these necessary and sufficient?  Is there anything else I need to consider?

Please remember this is *only* for concerns on the CLIENT-SIDE.  I have almost no control over the server itself.

Comment: I strongly recommend going over https (with a valid cert), together with whatever else you are going to do. You might think you can get away without it, but pretty much everyone screws it up.

Comment: You encrypt something with the public key, and unencrypt it with a private key. People often get this backwards.

Comment: @Tom: Yeah it seems that's the prevailing argument!  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Jared: So, I thought if I wanted the contents HIDDEN I do that.  Since I don't care about privacy, and want only verification, don't I switch that around?  Am I completely lost? (And Tom said people often get this wrong why ;)? )  I mean, anyone can encrypt a file with my public key.  Supposedly only I can do that with my private key.  The point's moot since I'll be using https, but for academic's sake it'd be good to know.

Comment: Just use a checksum against the downloadable file. As Tim mentions, it's hard to work out problems, and going to that kind of effort for non-repudiation is too much, IMO. A checksum or a digital signature (which is not encryption, although it's similar) is all you need for that. Plus, use HTTPS for transport security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you retrieve all of the information over https and check for a valid certificate then you can be sure that the data is coming from you server.

Comment: Adding a checksum would still be a good idea, just another layer of safety.

Comment: https + checksum is what I'm going with.  I will not do any encryption of the files on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

If I can compromise the server that delivers the patch, and the checksum is on the same server, then I can compromise the checksum.

Encrypting the patch is mainly useful if you do not use SSL to deliver the file.

The user that executes a program is usually not authorized to write to the installation directory (for security reasons; this applies to desktop applications as well as e.g. PHP scripts on a web server). You will have to take that into account when figuring out a way how to install the patch.

Answer (score 1):

The checksums are only as strong as the site from which they're downloaded.
If you use an asymmetric signature, so that the auto-update client has the public key, then you can sign your updates instead, and it won't matter if someone hacks your website, as long as they don't get the private key.